# Why there is no DATE and/or TIME entries in MySQL grammar in Antlr4?

Tags: mysql, datetime, antlr4

Here is the grammar for MySQL: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/mysql

Unfortunately, I don't see a word about date and time constants. For example, about YYYY MM DD?

Why?

Comment: Because they are builtin functions, not keywords.

Comment: "They" are who?

Comment: They are the "date" and "time" functions.

Comment: I meant why there are no definition for date time constants?

Comment: A grammar check does not include a type check. As long as there is "something" there (that is allowed by the grammar), it is fine for a grammar checker - including btw. the internal mysql parser: it will just raise an exception when(=after) it happens. Mysql will not complain about most things as long as it can somehow parse it to what it needs. E.g. `where date(now()) = 2016-12-06` (instead of `where date(now()) = '2016-12-06'`) will work. It will not be a date though. It will calculate `2016-12-06 = 1998` and compare that to `'2016-12-06'`. Would be hard for a grammar checker to "know" that.

Comment: 'They' are the '`date` and `time` constants' you are asking about. What else would they be? NB 'They' are not constants either. You seem to be seriously confused. Constants wouldn't appear in the grammar either.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: this grammar is just a toy. It only implements a very small subset of MySQL. A 100% complete grammar is here ([part of MySQL Workbench](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/master/library/mysql.parser/grammar/MySQL.g)). However, this is still for ANTLR3. The variant for ANTLR4 will be published with the next MySQL Workbench release (and then also linked from the ANTLR grammar directory).